# angularjs Add one column to json data

Tags: json, angularjs

I want to add a color column dynamically to the "solutions" table. My code is based on angularjs and json. I tried the following:

```
$scope.solutions.push({"color": value2.color});
```

The value2.color is dynamically decided by a forEach loop, but I was not able to add new column, did i do something wrong? Here is the Plunker URL: http://plnkr.co/edit/5gK5cBRdLQ6s8Gyy6ad8?p=preview

thanks!

Comment: it's correct. Is it show any error?

Comment: can you post a link to your full javascript source?  perhaps a [plunker](http://plnkr.co)

Comment: Is the reason you are calling it value2 that it is the second argument provided by the foreach?  The second argument is the key, try value1.color.  Just a thought.

Comment: did you initialized the scope variable? like `$scope.house=[]` ....

Comment: @vamsikrishnamannem thanks for the quick reply, but no..there are no errors in the console.

Comment: @bluetoft yes! here is the plunker link, if that makes sense... thank u in advance! http://plnkr.co/edit/5gK5cBRdLQ6s8Gyy6ad8?p=preview

Comment: hi, @Aaron, the value2 is the value, not a key. sorry i should have provided more information. see the plunker link.

Comment: @Moogs well, that is good to know. i thought this might be my silly mistake, and genesis people here can point it out by just one line code.. anyway,  i provided the plunker link, would this work?

Comment: @RameshRajendran yes~~ the scope got all the content from the url, which contatins all the json data. does that make sense?

Comment: @Lisa thanks for providing the plunker :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of pushing the object to the array, you need to get the object at that index and add the new property.

```
angular.forEach($scope.solutions, function(value1, i) {
    angular.forEach($scope.eliminations, function(value2, j) {
        if (value1.alien === value2.alien && value1.world === value2.world){
            $scope.solutions[i].color = value2.color;
        }
    });
});
```

**Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/reLCNHT1XvVuwRSF3873?p=preview**

Comment: Thanks! It seems working on plunker, but for some reason, it does not even execute the forEach loop if i don't manually put those two arrays there. even if i hard coded those two arrays, the color value could not pass to the view when i filter it by name.

Comment: alright! it works! i made a silly mistake by putting the loop in wrong place. thanks so much! but why .push did not work, while the index way works?

Comment: @Lisa push appends the item to the array, so it's not modifying the object in the array.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to edit your plunker as I can't call pull your solutions or eliminations data structures.  But as Ramesh Rajendran said above, the .push only works for initialized arrays

You need to create an array on your scope

```
  $scope.solutionsArray = [];
```

and instead of pushing to $scope.solutions you need to push to $scope.solutionsArray.

You also need to update your view by adding soultionsArray to your ng-reapeat

```
  <tr ng-repeat="solution in solutionsArray | filter:SelectedStudent.student_name | filter: {student_name: ''}" >
```

This is the best I could do without seeing your data structures.  I hope this helps! goood luck

Comment: hi, Aaron, thank you for the reply! I updated the plunker, and i believe that $scope.solutions is a json array. and i wanted to push the color filed in eliminations array to solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to update your code to something like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.solutions, function(value1, key1) {
    angular.forEach($scope.eliminations, function(value2, key2){
        if(value1.alien === value2.alien && value1.world === value2.world){
            console.log(value2.color);
            // value1 is a solution object in the solutions array
            value1["color"] = value2.color;

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: right...but i don't have the"color" key in solutions array, so it did not work...thanks though